# align text on axis to start at same position

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please have a look at my plot. Is it possible to force the text on the y-axis to start at the same position (and not end at the same position which is the case now)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `theme` to adjust the `axis.text.y`. Just use `hjust = 0` to get left alignment. So altogether, just add this line to your plot:

```
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

And here is a reproducible example that produces something similar to your plot.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = rownames(mtcars), fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0))
```